# Setting up Hotspot, I get Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection

Tags: network-manager, hot-spot, nmcli, ap-hotspot

Using Ubuntu 18.04 and a TP Link WN722Nv2 USB to Wireless adaptor I have been unable to setup a WiFi hotspot.

I have tested the H/W on 18.04, connecting to a WiFi router, which works fine.  I have tested the H/W on Windows 10 and it works fine as a hotspot.

The adaptor shows up as wlxd03745a3c52b.  The networkmanager logging didn't show anything that meant anything to me.

I have created a script which produces the following results:

```
$ ./hotspot.sh
+ VAR_HOTSPOT=TEST
+ sudo nmcli general logging level TRACE domains WIFI
[sudo] password for mark: 

+ nmcli radio
WIFI-HW  WIFI     WWAN-HW  WWAN    
enabled  enabled  enabled  enabled 

+ nmcli device show wlxd03745a3c52b
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlxd03745a3c52b
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         D0:37:45:A3:C5:2B
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --

+ nmcli connection delete TEST
Connection 'TEST' (30b71b57-79df-4fae-b7bf-004bf696cf9b) successfully deleted.

+ nmcli connection add type wifi ifname wlxd03745a3c52b con-name TEST autoconnect yes ssid LOGIKA
Connection 'TEST' (7d00b7ae-5e8d-4867-b440-e82da480f764) successfully added.
+ nmcli connection modify TEST wifi.mode ap wifi.band bg ipv4.method shared
+ nmcli connection modify TEST wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
+ nmcli con modify TEST wifi-sec.proto rsn
+ nmcli con modify TEST wifi-sec.pairwise ccmp
+ nmcli con modify TEST wifi-sec.group ccmp
+ nmcli con modify TEST wifi-sec.psk [password]
+ nmcli -p connection up TEST
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.

+ nmcli -s connection show TEST
connection.id:                          TEST
connection.uuid:                        7d00b7ae-5e8d-4867-b440-e82da480f764
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
connection.interface-name:              wlxd03745a3c52b
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   0
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
802-11-wireless.ssid:                   LOGIKA
802-11-wireless.mode:                   ap
802-11-wireless.band:                   bg
802-11-wireless.channel:                0
802-11-wireless.bssid:                  --
802-11-wireless.rate:                   0
802-11-wireless.tx-power:               0
802-11-wireless.mac-address:            --
802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address:     --
802-11-wireless.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-11-wireless.mac-address-blacklist:  --
802-11-wireless.mac-address-randomization:default
802-11-wireless.mtu:                    auto
802-11-wireless.seen-bssids:            --
802-11-wireless.hidden:                 no
802-11-wireless.powersave:              0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt:      wpa-psk
802-11-wireless-security.wep-tx-keyidx: 0
802-11-wireless-security.auth-alg:      --
802-11-wireless-security.proto:         rsn
802-11-wireless-security.pairwise:      ccmp
802-11-wireless-security.group:         ccmp
802-11-wireless-security.pmf:           0 (default)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-username: --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key0:      --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key1:      --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key2:      --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key3:      --
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-flags: 0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wep-key-type:  unknown
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           [password]
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password: --
802-11-wireless-security.leap-password-flags:0 (none)
802-11-wireless-security.wps-method:    0 (default)
ipv4.method:                            shared
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       ""
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       ""
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
```

I've tried various combinations of WiFi security options but all produce similar results or references to 802.1x supplicant taking too long.

I'm running out of ideas and would be grateful for any suggestions.  Are there other USB to WiFi adaptors that are known to work better?